# Glass framed shower door missing magnet

Tags: shower, corrosion, magnet

I bought a house with a builder grade glass framed shower.

The door is missing the magnet that keeps it closed. It appears that whatever attached the magnet to the frame corroded, so it's not obvious how to add a new magnet.

The metal strike on the door handle that the magnet should attach to is still in good condition.

What is the best way to go about getting a new magnet?

[image: missing magnet]
[image: strike plate]

Comment: If you can find a manufacturer name on any of the door/wall hardware, contact them for replacement parts. If that fails, use calipers to measure the thickness of the glass that the magnet attaches to and find a replacement part at your local home center that will fit.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a magnet.

Buy some construction adhesive. Or epoxy putty.

Apply adhesive to magnet, tape or clamp in place, leave until adhesive cures.

Comment: Encapsulate said magnet in polyurethane or something, in case it's the type that rusts...

Comment: I tried epoxy but it popped off

Comment: @TimHopper Usually that's either not clean enough, (residual soap is an issue with shower surfaces) or not cured long enough (i.e. the fine print on "2-hour" epoxy will mention that full strength is not achieved for 24 hours or more) - I would also counsel avoiding "5-minute" epoxy entirely.